# How do I split a data frame based on range of column values in R?

Tags: r, split, subset

I have a data set like this:

```
Users   Age
1        2
2        7
3        10
4        3
5        8
6        20
```

How do I split this data set into 3 data sets where the first consists of all users with ages between 0–5, second is 6–10 and third is 11–15?

Comment: See `?split` and `?subset`

Answer (score 13):

You can combine `split` with `cut` to do this in a single line of code, avoiding the need to subset with a bunch of different expressions for different data ranges:

```
split(dat, cut(dat$Age, c(0, 5, 10, 15), include.lowest=TRUE))
# $`[0,5]`
#   Users Age
# 1     1   2
# 4     4   3
# 
# $`(5,10]`
#   Users Age
# 2     2   7
# 3     3  10
# 5     5   8
# 
# $`(10,15]`
# [1] Users Age  
# <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

`cut` splits up data based on the specified break points, and `split` splits up a data frame based on the provided categories. If you stored the result of this computation into a list called `l`, you could access the smaller data frames with `l[[1]]`, `l[[2]]`, and `l[[3]]` or the more verbose:

```
l$`[0,5]`
l$`(5,10]`
l$`(10, 15]`
```

Answer (score 1):

First, here's your dataset for my purposes: `foo=data.frame(Users=1:6,Age=c(2,7,10,3,8,20))`

Here's your first dataset with ages 0–5: `subset(foo,Age<=5&Age>=0)`

```
  Users Age
1     1   2
4     4   3
```

Here's your second with ages 6–10: `subset(foo,Age<=10&Age>=6)`

```
  Users Age
2     2   7
3     3  10
5     5   8
```

Your third (using `subset(foo,Age<=15&Age>=11)`) is empty – your last `Age` observation is over 15.

Note also that fractional ages between 5 and 6 or 10 and 11 (e.g., 5.1, 10.5) would be excluded, as this code matches your question very literally. If you'd want someone with an age less than 6 to go in the first group, just amend that code to `subset(foo,Age<6&Age>=0)`. If you'd prefer a hypothetical person with `Age=5.1` in the second group, that group's code would be `subset(foo,Age<=10&Age>5)`.

Answer (score 1):

We could also use the `between` function from the `data.table` package.

```
# Create a data frame
dat <- data.frame(Users = 1:7, Age = c(2, 7, 10, 3, 8, 12, 15))

# Convert the data frame to data table by reference
# (data.table is also a data.frame)
setDT(dat)

# Define a list with the cut pairs
cuts <- list(c(0, 5), c(6, 10), c(11, 15))

# Cycle through dat and cut it into list of data tables by the values in Age
# matching the defined cuts
lapply(X = cuts, function(i) {
  dat[between(x = dat[ , Age], lower = i[1], upper = i[2])]
})
```

Output:

```
[[1]]
   Users Age
1:     1   2
2:     4   3

[[2]]
   Users Age
1:     2   7
2:     3  10
3:     5   8

[[3]]
   Users Age
1:     6  12
2:     7  15
```

Many other things are possible, including doing it by group, `data.table` is rather flexible.